# Only create dictionary once - and use that when dictionary is being called?

Tags: c#, dictionary, static

I am currently working on *refactoring some code*, where I have stumbled upon this `static` dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> CountryNamesAndCodes()
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   
    dictionary.Add("AF", "Afghanistan");
    dictionary.Add("AL", "Albania");
    dictionary.Add("DZ", "Algeria");
    dictionary.Add("AD", "Andorra");
    dictionary.Add("AO", "Angola");
    dictionary.Add("AG", "Antigua and Barbuda");
    dictionary.Add("AR", "Argentina");
    dictionary.Add("AM", "Armenia");
    ...
}
```

Which first of all is defined in the service layer, and takes up a lot a space - `400` lines, and eventhough it is `static`, it seem to always recreate the dictionary, meaning making the static part of it redundant - or am I wrong?

how do I ensure that this is only created once, and everytime I call it, it make use of the same instance.

Comment: You should (1) make it a static field and (2) use lazy (and threadsafe) initialisation using [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-6.0)

Comment: It depends on the context. If this is not being modified, it doesn't really matter, and you shoud make it an ImmutableDictionary.  If it is being changed on multiple threads, you should use a thread safe type such as ConcurrentDictionary.  If this is behind a load balancer, it doens't work at all, and you need it out of proc.

Comment: @Ian You may want to benchmark `IReadonlyDictionary d = new Dictionary...` against using an actual `ImmutableDictionary`. As far as I remember it's actually a different DataStructure "under the hood" with different O-Notation ...

Comment: the content of dictionary will not change nothing will be added to or changed, without required a redeploy. 

So using IReadOnlyDictionary is fine as I see it. 

The only problem I seem to have is ensuring that the IReadOnlyDictionary i search through is always the same instance, and never gets recreated.

Comment: @Fildor I'm commenting on integrity/reliability not performance.  Using contructs which help programmers not to compromise the system should be the first port of call.  There maybe performance concerns which lead to trade-offs to that principle, but that's a sepearte discussion.

Comment: @Fildor Edit: Sorry, missed the IReadOnly bit - yes that also does the same (ish), and may well be more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite right, you can extract the *local* dictionary as a *static* member

I suggest something like this (field):

```
// static readonly (we want to create it once) field of
// IReadOnlyDictionary type - we want to read key value pairs after its creation 
private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> countries = 
  // We may want to be nice and let ignore case for keys  
  new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    { "AF", "Afghanistan" },
    { "AL", "Albania" },
    { "DZ", "Algeria" },
    //TODO:Put all the other records here    
  };
```

or like this (property):

```
// static readonly (there's no "set") property of
// IReadOnlyDictionary type - we want just to read key value pairs after its creation 
private static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> Countries { get; } = 
  new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    { "AF", "Afghanistan" },
    { "AL", "Albania" },
    { "DZ", "Algeria" },
    //TODO:Put all the other records here
};
```

Comment: but does this not have the same problem as the other one?
A get call will return a new dictionary?

Comment: @static: no, `Countries { get; } = new ...` is *initialization* which will be perfomed *just once* (please, note `=`) before first read; if, however, you put `Countries { get; } => new ...` you'll get *new instance* each time you call the property (note, `=>`)

Answer (score -2):

```
public static class Globals
{
    static Dictionary<string, string> 
    CountryNamesAndCodes = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {   
        {"AF", "Afghanistan"},
        {"AL", "Albania"}
    };
}

name = Globals.CountryNamesAndCodes["AF"];
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).